# How to control the position of edit control in ListView

Tags: listview, winapi

I have used the `CreateWindow` function to create a ListView control with style `LVS_EDITLABELS`.

```
HWND hWndEditBox = CreateWindow(...LVS_EDITLABELS | LVS_OWNERDRAWFIXED | LVS_REPORT...);
```

It looks good, except for only one problem:

The edit control was alway in the first column of an item, no matter which sub item I click.

I got infomation from MSDN that says:

> you can get the handle of a edit control using the macro `ListView_GetEditControl`, then you can subclass the edit control

I did, but nothing changed.

From debugging:

```
EditBoxProc >> USER_DEFINED_MSG >> xy[80,20],wh[180,60]
EditBoxProc >> WM_MOVE >> xy[80,20]
EditBoxProc >> WM_SIZE >> xy[3,0],wh[180,60]
EditBoxProc >> WM_MOVE >> xy[2,40]
EditBoxProc >> WM_SIZE >> xy[3,0],wh[80,20]
```

Comment: LVS_EDITLABELS does not support sub-item editing if that's what your asking. If you need that functionality look for a 3rd party grid control.

Comment: @AlexK. It is possible to manipulate the native ListView edit control for subitem editing, [I've done it before](http://cc.embarcadero.com/Item/19226), but it is not trivial, and it is not supported by Microsoft. The code at that link was written for C++Builder's VCL UI wrapper (TListView), which is a thin wrapper for the Win32 LISTVIEW control, so the concepts can be adapted for pure Win32 code.

Comment: You'll need to show us the actual code if you want us to try to work out what's wrong.